# Function decorators in Ruby, as in Python

Tags: python, ruby, function, functional-programming, decorator

Is there a way to decorate a function in Ruby as it's done in Python? That is, have something execute at the beginning (and end?) of each function.

Like this: http://programmingbits.pythonblogs.com/27_programmingbits/archive/50_function_decorators.html

Comment: I think an example would help (particularly for those of us who are not very familiar with python)

Comment: Ah, I meant function decorators. Pardon me! I'll add an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by function you mean closure, you could use a block:

```
def foo
  puts 'before code'

  yield

  puts 'after code'
end

foo { puts 'here is the code' }
```

Comment: Is there nothing like the `@wrapper` syntax though?

Comment: You might find this post and the ensuing discussion interesting: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/07/11/python-decorators-in-ruby/

Answer (score 2):

The `alias_method` facility can be used to achieve this effect:

```
alias_method :old_foo, :foo
def foo
  # ... before stuff ...
  r = old_foo
  # ... after stuff ...
  return r
end
```

Within Ruby on Rails you can use `alias_method_chain` to do some of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Python's decorator syntax (which may not be exactly the functionality you're seeking to emulate) can be achieved in ruby by mixing in a module which modifies the decorated class' methods, as described succinctly in "[Decorator Pattern with Ruby in 8 lines](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/decorator-pattern-with-ruby-in-8-lines.html)" by Luke Redpath.

Comment: The decorator pattern for objects is different from Python's decorator feature for functions and methods.

Comment: Would you mind outlining the difference briefly for my benefit? =)

Comment: The decorator design pattern is used to add functionality to an existing class dynamically. The Python function decorator modifies the behavior of a function or method.

Comment: The link to that page is broken